# issue : docker-desktop-data is missing

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

When i installed the docker desktop exe file version : 4.8.1,

i am unable to start the application settings and autometically one popup appearing

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3jPi.png)

The actual stack trace inside image is :

```
Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
 stdout: Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature, the legacy console must be disabled.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 178
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

When i diagnosed with the command : **& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe" check**

Then i got the [diagnosed issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWWTe.png)

WSL Distribution docker-desktop-data is missing, it says.

When i ran the command : wsl -l -v

i got : [description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JN6k.png)

If i am trying to run any docker command then : [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYSAs.png)

i am getting

I am not sure what to do next, i have already uninstalled WSL and then again installed it and set it to WSL2 then again installed the docker desktop after removing all the temp files from C drive and Appdata folder.

If anyone know the solution to this please respond.

Comment: I tried to install the lower version of docker 4.5.1 but the same issue is still there.

Comment: WSL 2 does not work with Legacy Console, not a docker issue. Go to the properties of your console (click left top -> properties for example), on the options tab on the bottom uncheck "use legacy console (requires relaunch)" and relaunch.

Comment: @FrancescodeGuytenaere Thankyou for the response, but i have already unticked the legacy console. but the issue is also here that whenever i am running any docker command then it says : error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdock
er_engine/v1.24/auth": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

I did try to switch the daemon but still no change in error message.